# Bootstrap not getting installed in angular

Tags: angular

I had created a new project in angular. For installing bootstrap I gave the command "npm install bootstrap" . Instead of installing the package it provided the following  error :
Error :

- bootstrap@4.5.0
  updated 1 package and audited 1477 packages in 23.422s

50 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 3 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 1 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

As per my understood immediately i typed "npm audit" but though I was unable to install the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

- Install jquery

  npm install jquery
- Install popper

  npm install popper
- Edit your angular.json file:

1. Add the following entry to "styles" array:

   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
2. Add the following entries to "scripts" array, in this order:

   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/popper/client/tape/client.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

- Stop the "ng serve" command and run it again.

Explanation:

In your case, bootstrap was previously in your package.json file, and npm updated it. Bootstrap also needs jquery and popper to work.

What you needed to do was to import jquery, popper and bootstrap in your angular.json file, this is where the compiler looks up for scripts that it may need.

Comment: Another option is not use bootstrap nor jquery. Of course you can use bootstrap.css, but really the use of jQuery are not recomemded, I suggest use ng-bootstrap:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home insted of this

Comment: that's a valid answer, another option is to just include bootstrap via cdn